# How to reset the pinch zoom dynamically on ios chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, chrome-ios

want to reset the pinch zoomed web page using button click on ios chrome browser.

```
$('meta[name=viewport]').prop('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');
```

added this to reset pinch zoom in earlier versions of ios chrome browser. but not working in new versions.